# How to add a div around the default gallery output

Tags: gallery

I would like to add a container around the default [gallery] output. I don't want to modify any core files, and add unusual lines to my functions.php. How to do that? What's the most elegant method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you don't want to edit core files (which is absolutely fine, and unnecessary) and also don't want to do it by means of PHP (meaning `functions.php`, for instance), here's a jQuery approach:

```
$('div[id^="galleryid-"]').wrap('<div id="SOME_ID" class="SOME_CLASS" />');
```

BTW, you know there already is a container `div` that you can hijack for CSS purposes, right?

Comment: yes, there is a div with gallery class, but I need one more for a slider plugin. Is it the only solution? Dont you have a small code like this but with php?

Comment: No, I'm afraid there is no _short_ PHP solution. If you want to use the `post_gallery` filter, for instance, the code would be much longer. But why don't use the jQuery function? Do you have difficulties using/implementing it? Do you have anything against jQuery _per se_?

Comment: No, I can implement it. I don't like to use javascript to modify the structure. But I need to use it, because I don't want to use long php code for that. Thank you!